# How can I get the MediaWiki "Rp" template to work on my wiki?

Tags: mediawiki, template, wiki

I copy-pasted the contents of the English Wikipedia's [code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Rp) for creating the `{{rp}}` operator (that gives you the page number for a book) to [this page](http://health-and-medicine.wikia.com/wiki/Template:Rp). Then I followed all the errors that resulted, creating new templates so that the templates it relied on could be available.

If this seems unclear in my wording, please ask for clarifications.

Comment: I made some clarifications to this, feel free to modify as needed. Thanks for checking if this would be on topic [here](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1233/as-per-the-question-on-meta-i-link-can-i-ask-questions-about-wikia-here) first - hope you receive a helpful answer.

Comment: So, it still doesn't work even after you also copied the templetes it depends on? What does it do now?

Comment: Yes, there were like four templates I had to copy over, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide more information about what exactly doesn't work.  To be able to solve your problem, we would need to hear about the expected behavior and what differs from that.  Including any remaining error messages is also important.